# BigQuery stored procedure to capture table name along with number of records for that table name

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I have created the following stored procedure in BigQuery to get a list of table names along with a count for each of the table name.  I have come across 2 issues that I am not able to resolve.

#1 - How do I execute a count for each table in my "Execute Immediate" Sql statement?

#2 - My array results "tbl_lst_array" contains more than 800 tables but yet the stored procedure (when executed) only returns 100 rows.  Is it because of the following quota imposed by Google?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

I am processing one table at a time thru the loop.

Thank you for your help.

```
create procedure SP_MERGE.SP_bq_table_counts()

BEGIN
   DECLARE tbl_lst_array ARRAY<STRING>;
   DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_results(field STRING);  
   
   SET tbl_lst_array = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(table_schema||'.'||table_name) FROM `tng-edw-data-dev`.EDW.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES);   
   
   WHILE (i < ARRAY_LENGTH(tbl_lst_array)) DO
   
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
        INSERT tbl_results
            SELECT "''' || tbl_lst_array[ORDINAL(i)] || '''"
        ''';
     
        # Increment counter
        SET i = i + 1;
     
   END WHILE;   

   select * from tbl_results;
   
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point is valid. Instead of doing 1 insert job for every iteration, make sure you do collect/concat them and execute at the end of the loop 1 single insert job with all rows. This way you avoid the concurrent job limitations.